# Android linphone app crashes while in background

Tags: android, linphone, linphone-sdk

I am working on android an android app using linphone sdk. I have changed the package name to com.spoke. While the app is in background it crashes and shows the following error in logcat. What is the reason behind this error in android linphone? How to resolve this issue?

LogCat Output:

```
 A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 20247 (FinalizerDaemon)
 I/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
 I/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'samsung/lt013gxx/lt013g:4.4.2/KOT49H/T311XXUBNH6:user/release-keys'
 I/DEBUG: Revision: '7'
 I/DEBUG: pid: 20238, tid: 20247, name: FinalizerDaemon  >>> com.spoke <<<
 I/DEBUG: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000000
 I/DEBUG:     r0 61edb078  r1 00000025  r2 619e4ed8  r3 6279b000
 I/DEBUG:     r4 57e884e8  r5 00000025  r6 61ef3690  r7 619faa7c
 I/DEBUG:     r8 619e4ed8  r9 5ad24f5c  sl 5e410fe8  fp 5ccf1b24
 I/DEBUG:     ip 00000002  sp 5ccf1ae8  lr 6179ba28  pc 00000000  cpsr 80070010
 I/DEBUG:     d0  706e696c65726e75  d1  726f632f656e6f68
 I/DEBUG:     d2  6f68706e694c2f65  d3  49746e657645656e
 I/DEBUG:     d4  70615f6465726168  d5  703d657079742070
 I/DEBUG:     d6  5f6d726f6674616c  d7  617461645f707061
 I/DEBUG:     d8  0000000000000000  d9  0000000000000000
 I/DEBUG:     d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
 I/DEBUG:     d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
 I/DEBUG:     d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
 I/DEBUG:     d16 000000000000001c  d17 3fc999999999999a
 I/DEBUG:     d18 4146605000000000  d19 0065004e005f0061
 I/DEBUG:     d20 3f8948b0fcd6e9e0  d21 3fe555b0aaeac752
 I/DEBUG:     d22 3fd24998d6307188  d23 3fcc7288e957b53b
 I/DEBUG:     d24 3fc74721cad6b0ed  d25 3fc2f112df3e5244
 I/DEBUG:     d26 40026bb1bbb55516  d27 4000000000000000
 I/DEBUG:     d28 40008df2d49d41f1  d29 3fb0f4a31edab38b
 I/DEBUG:     d30 3ff0000000000000  d31 3f4de16b9c24a98f
 I/DEBUG:     scr 80000010
 I/DEBUG: backtrace:
 I/DEBUG:     #00  pc 00000000  <unknown>
 I/DEBUG:     #01  pc 000faa24  /data/app-lib/com.spoke-1/liblinphone-armeabi-v7a.so (belle_sip_object_cast+68)
 I/DEBUG:     #02  pc 000fb640  /data/app-lib/com.spoke-1/liblinphone-armeabi-v7a.so (belle_sip_object_unref+36)
 I/DEBUG:     #03  pc 0001ea0c  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+112)
 I/DEBUG:     #04  pc 0004efab  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+398)
 I/DEBUG:     #05  pc 00027e20  /system/lib/libdvm.so
 I/DEBUG:     #06  pc 0002ee04  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmMterpStd(Thread*)+76)
 I/DEBUG:     #07  pc 0002c49c  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+184)
 I/DEBUG:     #08  pc 00061409  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)+336)
 I/DEBUG:     #09  pc 0006142d  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethod(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, JValue*, ...)+20)
 I/DEBUG:     #10  pc 00056107  /system/lib/libdvm.so
 I/DEBUG:     #11  pc 0000d298  /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
 I/DEBUG:     #12  pc 0000d430  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+240)
 I/DEBUG: stack:
 I/DEBUG:          5ccf1aa8  61ed4540  
 I/DEBUG:          5ccf1aac  5e410fd8  
 I/DEBUG:          5ccf1ab0  61ef3690  
 I/DEBUG:          5ccf1ab4  61ed4548  
 I/DEBUG:          5ccf1ab8  62373188  
 I/DEBUG:          5ccf1abc  5e410fd8  
 I/DEBUG:          5ccf1ac0  61ef3690  
 I/DEBUG:          5ccf1ac4  62373190  
 I/DEBUG:          5ccf1ac8  fffffea4  
 I/DEBUG:          5ccf1acc  41e3458c  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-zygote (deleted)
 I/DEBUG:          5ccf1ad0  41e34588  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-zygote (deleted)
 I/DEBUG:          5ccf1ad4  40069fb8  
 I/DEBUG:          5ccf1ad8  417d9c58  /system/lib/libdvm.so
 I/DEBUG:          5ccf1adc  417728e5  /system/lib/libdvm.so
 I/DEBUG:          5ccf1ae0  00000000  
 I/DEBUG:          5ccf1ae4  61ef3690  
 I/DEBUG:     #00  5ccf1ae8  57e884e8  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-LinearAlloc (deleted)
 I/DEBUG:          ........  ........
 I/DEBUG:     #01  5ccf1ae8  57e884e8  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-LinearAlloc (deleted)
 I/DEBUG:          5ccf1aec  5e410fd8  
 I/DEBUG:          5ccf1af0  00000000  
 I/DEBUG:          5ccf1af4  5ad24f64  
 I/DEBUG:          5ccf1af8  5ccf1b10  
 I/DEBUG:          5ccf1afc  6179c644  /data/app-lib/com.spoke-1/liblinphone-armeabi-v7a.so (belle_sip_object_unref+40)
 I/DEBUG:     #02  5ccf1b00  00000076  
 I/DEBUG:          5ccf1b04  00000001  
 I/DEBUG:          5ccf1b08  57e884e8  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-LinearAlloc (deleted)
 I/DEBUG:          5ccf1b0c  4173da10  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+116)
 I/DEBUG: memory near r0:
 I/DEBUG:     61edb058 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
 I/DEBUG:     61edb068 00000000 00000013 00313333 00000042  
 I/DEBUG:     61edb078 6279b000 00000049 61ee3768 61ef3688  
 I/DEBUG:     61edb088 00000002 00000000 0000005e 00000000  
 I/DEBUG:     61edb098 00000006 00000000 619d05d0 00000021  
 I/DEBUG:     61edb0a8 61ed9ed8 61ead340 619d0660 619d0f00  
 I/DEBUG:     61edb0b8 000003ba 619cdce0 00000048 0000001a  
 I/DEBUG:     61edb0c8 0000000a 00000002 4c2d6e65 2d6e7461  
 I/DEBUG:     61edb0d8 00004247 0000005b 5c7d8908 41400000  
 I/DEBUG:     61edb0e8 3f800000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
 I/DEBUG:     61edb0f8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
 I/DEBUG:     61edb108 00000000 00000000 00000000 ff000000  
 I/DEBUG:     61edb118 00000000 40800000 0b000506 62262730  
 I/DEBUG:     61edb128 00000001 00000001 00000005 0000001b  
 I/DEBUG:     61edb138 0000000a 00000001 4c2d6e65 2d6e7461  
 I/DEBUG:     61edb148 00004247 0000005b 5c7d8908 41400000  
 I/DEBUG: memory near r2:
 I/DEBUG:     619e4eb8 6620676e 6120726f 20726464 5d70255b  
 I/DEBUG:     619e4ec8 74697720 756e2068 75206c6c 00006972  
 I/DEBUG:     619e4ed8 6c6c6562 69735f65 626f5f70 7463656a  
 I/DEBUG:     619e4ee8 0000745f 6d6f682f 61722f65 616c7568  
 I/DEBUG:     619e4ef8 7261736e 694c2f69 6f68506e 6c2f656e  
 I/DEBUG:     619e4f08 68706e69 2d656e6f 72646e61 2f64696f  
 I/DEBUG:     619e4f18 6d627573 6c75646f 6c2f7365 68706e69  
 I/DEBUG:     619e4f28 2f656e6f 65726f63 2f697061 6c6c6562  
 I/DEBUG:     619e4f38 70697365 6c61735f 6c61732f 6464615f  
 I/DEBUG:     619e4f48 73736572 706d695f 00632e6c 73706973  
 I/DEBUG:     619e4f58 00000000 6c6c6562 69735f65 65685f70  
 I/DEBUG:     619e4f68 72656461 6464615f 73736572 0000745f  
 I/DEBUG:     619e4f78 6c6c6562 69735f65 61705f70 656d6172  
 I/DEBUG:     619e4f88 73726574 0000745f 6c6c6562 69732d65  
 I/DEBUG:     619e4f98 00000070 6d696e55 6d656c70 65746e65  
 I/DEBUG:     619e4fa8 41532064 6163204c 61626c6c 00006b63  
 I/DEBUG: memory near r3:
 I/DEBUG:     6279afe0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
 I/DEBUG:     6279aff0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
 I/DEBUG:     6279b000 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
 I/DEBUG:     6279b010 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
 I/DEBUG:     6279b020 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
 I/DEBUG:     6279b030 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
 I/DEBUG:     6279b040 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
 I/DEBUG:     6279b050 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
 I/DEBUG:     6279b060 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
 I/DEBUG:     6279b070 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
 I/DEBUG:     6279b080 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
 I/DEBUG:     6279b090 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
 I/DEBUG:     6279b0a0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
 I/DEBUG:     6279b0b0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
 I/DEBUG:     6279b0c0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
 I/DEBUG:     6279b0d0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
 I/DEBUG: memory near r4:
 I/DEBUG:     57e884c8 0000003e 60f0c84f 00000000 40000000  
 I/DEBUG:     57e884d8 4176f8d5 00000000 00000000 00000000  
 I/DEBUG:     57e884e8 42490c48 00000102 00030000 00030000  
 I/DEBUG:     57e884f8 60f620de 5c757ab8 000006eb 60f35fb3  
 I/DEBUG:     57e88508 6177e2f0 00000000 4176de1d 00000100  
 I/DEBUG:     57e88518 00000000 00000000 42490c48 00000102  
 I/DEBUG:     57e88528 00070000 00070000 60f62539 5c757ab8  
 I/DEBUG:     57e88538 00000049 60f0c88d 00000000 42000000  
 I/DEBUG:     57e88548 4176f8d5 00000000 00000000 00000000  
 I/DEBUG:     57e88558 42490c48 00000102 00070000 00070000  
 I/DEBUG:     57e88568 60f625d5 5c757ab8 00000049 60f0c88d  
 I/DEBUG:     57e88578 00000000 42000000 4176f8d5 00000000  
 I/DEBUG:     57e88588 00000000 00000000 00000000 0000042c  
 I/DEBUG:     57e88598 42490c48 00020001 0005000b 00010003  
 I/DEBUG:     57e885a8 60f3876a 5c757ab8 00000688 60f35ce9  
 I/DEBUG:     57e885b8 60ec5590 00000000 00000000 00000000  
 I/DEBUG: memory near r6:
 I/DEBUG:     61ef3670 00000000 40800000 0b000501 61eb6d60  
 I/DEBUG:     61ef3680 00000001 00000001 00000005 00000049  
 I/DEBUG:     61ef3690 61edb078 401651f0 00000000 00000000  
 I/DEBUG:     61ef36a0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001  
 I/DEBUG:     61ef36b0 5c7c4ab0 61ed4548 00000000 00000005  
 I/DEBUG:     61ef36c0 00000000 00000000 62373190 00000000  
 I/DEBUG:     61ef36d0 00000048 0000005a 61acf288 00000001  
 I/DEBUG:     61ef36e0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
 I/DEBUG:     61ef36f0 00000000 1d20089b 00000000 00000000  
 I/DEBUG:     61ef3700 00000000 00000001 00000000 00000000  
 I/DEBUG:     61ef3710 00000000 62383278 00000000 00000000  
 I/DEBUG:     61ef3720 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000079  
 I/DEBUG:     61ef3730 40165220 61f28340 00000004 00000070  
 I/DEBUG:     61ef3740 00000016 00000000 00000000 00000016  
 I/DEBUG:     61ef3750 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000016  
 I/DEBUG:     61ef3760 435fb848 00000000 61ef37a0 435fb848  
 I/DEBUG: memory near r7:
 I/DEBUG:     619faa5c 6e6f6974 0000002e 20646142 74736163  
 I/DEBUG:     619faa6c 206f7420 61207325 73252074 0069253a  
 I/DEBUG:     619faa7c 6d6f682f 61722f65 616c7568 7261736e  
 I/DEBUG:     619faa8c 694c2f69 6f68506e 6c2f656e 68706e69  
 I/DEBUG:     619faa9c 2d656e6f 72646e61 2f64696f 6d627573  
 I/DEBUG:     619faaac 6c75646f 622f7365 656c6c65 7069732d  
 I/DEBUG:     619faabc 6372732f 6c65622f 735f656c 6f5f7069  
 I/DEBUG:     619faacc 63656a62 00632e74 6c756f43 6f6e2064  
 I/DEBUG:     619faadc 69662074 7720646e 5f6b6165 2c666572  
 I/DEBUG:     619faaec 756f7920 20657227 6f6c2061 7265736f  
 I/DEBUG:     619faafc 0000002e 20646142 74736163 206f7420  
 I/DEBUG:     619fab0c 65746e69 63616672 73252065 20746120  
 I/DEBUG:     619fab1c 253a7325 00000069 656a624f 6f207463  
 I/DEBUG:     619fab2c 79742066 25206570 6f632073 74696d6d  
 I/DEBUG:     619fab3c 61206465 66756220 20726566 7265766f  
 I/DEBUG:     619fab4c 776f6c66 20796220 7372616d 6c6c6168  
 I/DEBUG: memory near r8:
 I/DEBUG:     619e4eb8 6620676e 6120726f 20726464 5d70255b  
 I/DEBUG:     619e4ec8 74697720 756e2068 75206c6c 00006972  
 I/DEBUG:     619e4ed8 6c6c6562 69735f65 626f5f70 7463656a  
 I/DEBUG:     619e4ee8 0000745f 6d6f682f 61722f65 616c7568  
 I/DEBUG:     619e4ef8 7261736e 694c2f69 6f68506e 6c2f656e  
 I/DEBUG:     619e4f08 68706e69 2d656e6f 72646e61 2f64696f  
 I/DEBUG:     619e4f18 6d627573 6c75646f 6c2f7365 68706e69  
 I/DEBUG:     619e4f28 2f656e6f 65726f63 2f697061 6c6c6562  
 I/DEBUG:     619e4f38 70697365 6c61735f 6c61732f 6464615f  
 I/DEBUG:     619e4f48 73736572 706d695f 00632e6c 73706973  
 I/DEBUG:     619e4f58 00000000 6c6c6562 69735f65 65685f70  
 I/DEBUG:     619e4f68 72656461 6464615f 73736572 0000745f  
 I/DEBUG:     619e4f78 6c6c6562 69735f65 61705f70 656d6172  
 I/DEBUG:     619e4f88 73726574 0000745f 6c6c6562 69732d65  
 I/DEBUG:     619e4f98 00000070 6d696e55 6d656c70 65746e65  
 I/DEBUG:     619e4fa8 41532064 6163204c 61626c6c 00006b63  
 I/DEBUG: memory near r9:
 I/DEBUG:     5ad24f3c 424c6610 41e1f718 5ad24f78 60ec568c  
 I/DEBUG:     5ad24f4c 57e884e8 00000000 00000000 75d00001  
 I/DEBUG:     5ad24f5c 61ef3690 00000000 5ad24f98 58b4d428  
 I/DEBUG:     5ad24f6c 57e88640 60ec568c 00000000 61ef3690  
 I/DEBUG:     5ad24f7c 00000000 424fdc78 5ad24fc8 58b4d4bc  
 I/DEBUG:     5ad24f8c 57af4610 58b4d428 61cac979 58b4d4b0  
 I/DEBUG:     5ad24f9c 424fdc78 41e34588 41e34588 00000000  
 I/DEBUG:     5ad24fac 41e342d0 424d4590 5ad24fe4 58b53248  
 I/DEBUG:     5ad24fbc 57af4650 58b4d4bc 00000000 424d4590  
 I/DEBUG:     5ad24fcc 41e342d0 5ad25000 00000000 57ab6ef0  
 I/DEBUG:     5ad24fdc 58b53248 00000000 41e342d0 424509f8  
 I/DEBUG:     5ad24fec 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
 I/DEBUG:     5ad24ffc 00000000 00000000 0000001b 41e33130  
 I/DEBUG:     5ad2500c 64696f72 696e612f 6974616d 412f6e6f  
 I/DEBUG:     5ad2501c 0000001b 41e33130 401651d0 6d696e61  
 I/DEBUG:     5ad2502c 6f697461 6e412e6e 0000001b 41e33130  
 I/DEBUG: memory near sl:
 I/DEBUG:     5e410fc8 d1d1d1d1 d1d1d1d1 00000000 0000045b  
 I/DEBUG:     5e410fd8 58c037f4 5ad24f58 57e88640 5e475000  
 I/DEBUG:     5e410fe8 41e34588 00001315 5ccf1c40 00000000  
 I/DEBUG:     5e410ff8 5ccf1c94 00000007 00000000 4173db80  
 I/DEBUG:     5e411008 00000000 00000000 57073d70 5ad21300  
 I/DEBUG:     5e411018 00000000 00000000 00000001 00004000  
 I/DEBUG:     5e411028 00000000 5e411430 4173db80 41742a40  
 I/DEBUG:     5e411038 00000000 41746b3c 41746bb0 41746a60  
 I/DEBUG:     5e411048 41746a80 41746adc 00000000 00000000  
 I/DEBUG:     5e411058 5c82a650 00000028 61cad249 5ccf1c40  
 I/DEBUG:     5e411068 58b4d40a 00000006 00002000 417df33c  
 I/DEBUG:     5e411078 41e39620 57ab20f0 00000001 5e411678  
 I/DEBUG:     5e411088 00000001 00000040 00000200 00000000  
 I/DEBUG:     5e411098 00000002 59298900 59298900 00000002  
 I/DEBUG:     5e4110a8 5929892e 57b00470 00000000 a4009d5c  
 I/DEBUG:     5e4110b8 52403282 00000000 00000000 00000000  
 I/DEBUG: memory near fp:
 I/DEBUG:     5ccf1b04 00000001 57e884e8 4173da10 5ad24f58  
 I/DEBUG:     5ccf1b14 00000001 00000000 424fdc78 424509f8  
 I/DEBUG:     5ccf1b24 4176dfaf 5ad24f58 60f35fb3 6177e2f0  
 I/DEBUG:     5ccf1b34 5e410fe8 00000000 5c753b00 00000000  
 I/DEBUG:     5ccf1b44 00000000 5c7c9db4 40165384 00000000  
 I/DEBUG:     5ccf1b54 5ccf1c40 00000000 5ccf1c94 00000000  
 I/DEBUG:     5ccf1b64 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
 I/DEBUG:     5ccf1b74 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
 I/DEBUG:     5ccf1b84 00000000 5ccf1bf4 57e884fc 00000001  
 I/DEBUG:     5ccf1b94 42490c48 0000000f 00000001 57e884e8  
 I/DEBUG:     5ccf1ba4 60f620de 5ccf1bf4 00000038 00000000  
 I/DEBUG:     5ccf1bb4 4178bd7f 60f620de 60dea1ec 42490c48  
 I/DEBUG:     5ccf1bc4 60f620de 5e475000 00003d8c 00000001  
 I/DEBUG:     5ccf1bd4 d9aeb97b 00000000 4004bc20 4176fad9  
 I/DEBUG:     5ccf1be4 d9aeb97b cbcacccd 41e3458c 41e34588  
 I/DEBUG:     5ccf1bf4 5e410fd8 00000007 00000038 1dcd64ff  
 I/DEBUG: memory near sp:
 I/DEBUG:     5ccf1ac8 fffffea4 41e3458c 41e34588 40069fb8  
 I/DEBUG:     5ccf1ad8 417d9c58 417728e5 00000000 61ef3690  
 I/DEBUG:     5ccf1ae8 57e884e8 5e410fd8 00000000 5ad24f64  
 I/DEBUG:     5ccf1af8 5ccf1b10 6179c644 00000076 00000001  
 I/DEBUG:     5ccf1b08 57e884e8 4173da10 5ad24f58 00000001  
 I/DEBUG:     5ccf1b18 00000000 424fdc78 424509f8 4176dfaf  
 I/DEBUG:     5ccf1b28 5ad24f58 60f35fb3 6177e2f0 5e410fe8  
 I/DEBUG:     5ccf1b38 00000000 5c753b00 00000000 00000000  
 I/DEBUG:     5ccf1b48 5c7c9db4 40165384 00000000 5ccf1c40  
 I/DEBUG:     5ccf1b58 00000000 5ccf1c94 00000000 00000000  
 I/DEBUG:     5ccf1b68 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
 I/DEBUG:     5ccf1b78 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
 I/DEBUG:     5ccf1b88 5ccf1bf4 57e884fc 00000001 42490c48  
 I/DEBUG:     5ccf1b98 0000000f 00000001 57e884e8 60f620de  
 I/DEBUG:     5ccf1ba8 5ccf1bf4 00000038 00000000 4178bd7f  
 I/DEBUG:     5ccf1bb8 60f620de 60dea1ec 42490c48 60f620de  
 I/DEBUG: code around pc:
 I/DEBUG:     00000000 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
 I/DEBUG:     00000010 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
 I/DEBUG:     00000020 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
 I/DEBUG:     00000030 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
 I/DEBUG:     00000040 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
 I/DEBUG:     00000050 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
 I/DEBUG:     00000060 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
 I/DEBUG:     00000070 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
 I/DEBUG:     00000080 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
 I/DEBUG:     00000090 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
 I/DEBUG:     000000a0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
 I/DEBUG:     000000b0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
 I/DEBUG:     000000c0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
 I/DEBUG:     000000d0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
 I/DEBUG:     000000e0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
 I/DEBUG:     000000f0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
 I/DEBUG: code around lr:
 I/DEBUG:     6179ba08 e1510003 1a000003 ea00000c e5904000  
 I/DEBUG:     6179ba18 e1550004 0a000009 e590c010 e12fff3c  
 I/DEBUG:     6179ba28 e3500000 1afffff8 e59f0018 e1a01008  
 I/DEBUG:     6179ba38 e1a02007 e59d3018 e08f0000 ebfffe01  
 I/DEBUG:     6179ba48 e1a00006 e8bd81f0 0025f01c e92d40f0  
 I/DEBUG:     6179ba58 e24dd00c e1a05002 e3a03095 e59f2048  
 I/DEBUG:     6179ba68 e1a06001 e58d3000 e3a01025 e59f303c  
 I/DEBUG:     6179ba78 e08f2002 e08f3003 ebffffd6 e1a04000  
 I/DEBUG:     6179ba88 e590700c e3a0000c eb001a35 e1a03000  
 I/DEBUG:     6179ba98 e5806004 e1a00004 e5835008 e584300c  
 I/DEBUG:     6179baa8 e5837000 e28dd00c e8bd80f0 00249458  
 I/DEBUG:     6179bab8 0025eff8 e92d41f0 e24dd008 e3a0309d  
 I/DEBUG:     6179bac8 e1a08002 e58d3000 e1a05001 e59f209c  
 I/DEBUG:     6179bad8 e3a01025 e59f3098 e08f2002 e08f3003  
 I/DEBUG:     6179bae8 ebffffbc e5903004 e1a07000 e3730001  
 I/DEBUG:     6179baf8 0a000019 e590000c e3500000 13a02000  
 I/DEBUG: !@dumpstate -k -t -z -d -o /data/log/dumpstate_app_native -m 20238
 I/BootReceiver: Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_05 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
 W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.spoke/org.linphone.LinphoneActivity
 I/dumpstate: begin
 I/dumpstate: begin
 I/dumpstate: dumpstate is still running
 I/SpenGestureManager: setFocusWindow0
 D/PointerIcon: setMouseIconStyle1 pointerType: 1001iconType:101 flag:0
 D/PointerIcon: setMouseCustomIcon IconType is same.101
 D/STATUSBAR-StatusBarManagerService: manageDisableList what=0x0 pkg=WindowManager.LayoutParams
 I/SurfaceFlinger: id=260 createSurf (1x1),1 flag=4, tpoke
 D/KeyguardUpdateMonitor: sendKeyguardVisibilityChanged(true)
 I/KeyguardUpdateMonitor: visibility is same
 I/BootReceiver: Notify a SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE FilePath:tombstone_05
 W/ContextImpl: Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.sendBroadcast:1495 android.content.ContextWrapper.sendBroadcast:377 android.content.ContextWrapper.sendBroadcast:377 com.android.server.BootReceiver$2.onEvent:333 android.os.FileObserver$ObserverThread.onEvent:125 
 D/KeyguardUpdateMonitor: sendKeyguardVisibilityChanged(true)
 I/KeyguardUpdateMonitor: visibility is same
 D/KeyguardUpdateMonitor: sendKeyguardVisibilityChanged(true)
 I/KeyguardUpdateMonitor: visibility is same
 D/KeyguardUpdateMonitor: sendKeyguardVisibilityChanged(true)
 I/KeyguardUpdateMonitor: visibility is same
 D/CrashAnrDetector: Build: samsung/lt013gxx/lt013g:4.4.2/KOT49H/T311XXUBNH6:user/release-keys
                                                   Hardware: smdk4x12
                                                   Revision: 7
                                                   Bootloader: T311XXUBNH6
                                                   Radio: unknown
                                                   Kernel: Linux version 3.0.31-2376617 (dpi@SWDD5616) (gcc version 4.4.3 (GCC) ) #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu Aug 7 19:37:59 KST 2014

                                                   *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
                                                   Build fingerprint: 'samsung/lt013gxx/lt013g:4.4.2/KOT49H/T311XXUBNH6:user/release-keys'
                                                   Revision: '7'
                                                   pid: 20238, tid: 20247, name: FinalizerDaemon  >>> com.spoke <<<
                                                   signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000000
                                                       r0 61edb078  r1 00000025  r2 619e4ed8  r3 6279b000
                                                       r4 57e884e8  r5 00000025  r6 61ef3690  r7 619faa7c
                                                       r8 619e4ed8  r9 5ad24f5c  sl 5e410fe8  fp 5ccf1b24
                                                       ip 00000002  sp 5ccf1ae8  lr 6179ba28  pc 00000000  cpsr 80070010
                                                       d0  706e696c65726e75  d1  726f632f656e6f68
                                                       d2  6f68706e694c2f65  d3  49746e657645656e
                                                       d4  70615f6465726168  d5  703d657079742070
                                                       d6  5f6d726f6674616c  d7  617461645f707061
                                                       d8  0000000000000000  d9  0000000000000000
                                                       d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
                                                       d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
                                                       d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
                                                       d16 000000000000001c  d17 3fc999999999999a
                                                       d18 4146605000000000  d19 0065004e005f0061
                                                       d20 3f8948b0fcd6e9e0  d21 3fe555b0aaeac752
                                                       d22 3fd24998d6307188  d23 3fcc7288e957b53b
                                                       d24 3fc74721cad6b0ed  d25 3fc2f112df3e5244
                                                       d26 40026bb1bbb55516  d27 4000000000000000
                                                       d28 40008df2d49d41f1  d29 3fb0f4a31edab38b
                                                       d30 3ff0000000000000  d31 3f4de16b9c24a98f
                                                       scr 80000010

                                                   backtrace:
                                                       #00  pc 00000000  <unknown>
                                                       #01  pc 000faa24  /data/app-lib/com.spoke-1/liblinphone-armeabi-v7a.so (belle_sip_object_cast+68)
                                                       #02  pc 000fb640  /data/app-lib/com.spoke-1/liblinphone-armeabi-v7a.so (belle_sip_object_unref+36)
                                                       #03  pc 0001ea0c  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+112)
                                                       #04  pc 0004efab  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+398)
                                                       #05  pc 00027e20  /system/lib/libdvm.so
                                                       #06  pc 0002ee04  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmMterpStd(Thread*)+76)
                                                       #07  pc 0002c49c  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+184)
                                                       #08  pc 00061409  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)+336)
                                                       #09  pc 0006142d  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethod(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, JValue*, ...)+20)
                                                       #10  pc 00056107  /system/lib/libdvm.so
                                                       #11  pc 0000d298  /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
                                                       #12  pc 0000d430  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+240)

                                                   stack:
                                                            5ccf1aa8  61ed4540  
                                                            5ccf1aac  5e410fd8  
                                                            5ccf1ab0  61ef3690  
                                                            5ccf1ab4  61ed4548  
                                                            5ccf1ab8  62373188  
                                                            5ccf1abc  5e410fd8  
                                                            5ccf1ac0  61ef3690  
                                                            5ccf1ac4  62373190  
                                                            5ccf1ac8  fffffea4  
                                                            5ccf1acc  41e3458c  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-zygote (deleted)
                                                            5ccf1ad0  41e34588  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-zygote (deleted)
                                                            5ccf1ad4  40069fb8  
                                                            5ccf1ad8  417d9c58  /system/lib/libdvm.so
                                                            5ccf1adc  417728e5  /system/lib/libdvm.so
                                                            5ccf1ae0  00000000  
                                                            5ccf1ae4  61ef3690  
                                                       #00  5ccf1ae8  57e884e8  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-LinearAlloc (deleted)
                                                            ........  ........
                                                       #01  5ccf1ae8  57e884e8  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-LinearAlloc (deleted)
                                                            5ccf1aec  5e410fd8  
                                                            5ccf1af0  00000000  
                                                            5ccf1af4  5ad24f64  
                                                            5ccf1af8  5ccf1b10  
                                                            5ccf1afc  6179c644  /data/app-lib/com.spoke-1/liblinphone-armeabi-v7a.so (belle_sip_object_unref+40)
                                                       #02  5ccf1b00  00000076  
                                                            5ccf1b04  00000001  
                                                            5ccf1b08  57e884e8  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-LinearAlloc (deleted)
                                                            5ccf1b0c  4173da10  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+116)
                                                       #03  5ccf1b10  5ad24f58  
                                                            5ccf1b14  00000001  
                                                            5ccf1b18  00000000  
                                                            5ccf1b1c  424fdc78  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
                                                            5ccf1b20  424509f8  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
                                                            5ccf1b24
 D/CrashAnrDetector: processName:com.spoke
 D/CrashAnrDetector: broadcastEvent : com.spoke SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE
```

The app is working well as expected, but somtimes it crashes with these errors.

Comment: Please add the code that is associated with this error. Also, what have you tried doing so far?

Comment: logcat is not showing any error or exception due to code.